# IE9 only css error

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a site that looks off on IE9 and I cant figure out how to fix it without messing up all the other browsers.

On the right side you will see the alignment is off.

http://dietandweightloss.pixelworklab.com/

[image]

Comment: can you share a link or the relevant html and css?

Comment: @ile http://dietandweightloss.pixelworklab.com/

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following :

```
#featured-top-right {
    float: left;
}
```

And this should solve it.

Comment: also seems to be cutting off the training text below?